# Issue with providing Query parameter in @hapi/lab unit test

Tags: unit-testing, hapi.js

i am trying to implement testing using `@hapi/lab` and `@hapi/code` .
I am struct on how can i provide query parameter in order to test as there is no option to pass it in `Options`.
In my API, i have 2 parameter to pass, 1) JWT token which is `authorization` and 2) query `{ "name": "string" }`
please guide me how can i enter query parameter and then check according to it. This is my test case i created.

```
describe('Routes', () => {
  let server;
  let response;

  describe('with JWT token /dashboard', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
      server = await init();
    });

    it('it returns a 200', async () => {
      const authorization = await authenticate(server);
      const Options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/dashboard',
        headers: {
          authorization,
        },
      };
      response = await server.inject(Options);
      expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the

> server.inject({url:'/xyz?id='+term})

and declare

> const term = 'abc';

inside it block and this pass query parameter check